# Sorting on a column alphanumerically

Tags: sorting, columnsorting

I have following file and I want to sort it alphanumerically based on 6 th column such that an E1 is followed by I1 and then E2 and so on of a specific ID before the ' : ', when I do sort -V -k6 file it puts all the ID:Is at the end and not where they should be.However when I do sort -k6 it does put the Es and Is of the IDs together but with some IDs belonging to different series interspersed (I have highlighted them here), how can I get the sorting such that no two IDs are mixed and the column is in the order it should be:

```
chr1    259017  259121  104 -   ENSG00000228463:E2
chr1    259122  267095  7973    -   ENSG00000228463:I1
chr1    267096  267253  157 -   ENSG00000228463:E1
chr1    317720  317781  61  +   ENSG00000237094:E1
chr1    317782  320161  2379    +   ENSG00000237094:I1
chr1    320162  320653  491 +   ENSG00000237094:E2
chr1    320654  320880  226 +   ENSG00000237094:I2
chr1    320881  320938  57  +   ENSG00000237094:E3
chr1    320939  321031  92  +   ENSG00000237094:I3
chr1    321032  321290  258 +   ENSG00000237094:E4
chr1    321291  322037  746 +   ENSG00000237094:I4
chr1    322038  322228  190 +   ENSG00000237094:E5
chr1    322229  322671  442 +   ENSG00000237094:I5
chr1    322672  323073  401 +   ENSG00000237094:E6
chr1    323074  323860  786 +   ENSG00000237094:I6
chr1    323861  324060  199 +   ENSG00000237094:E7
chr1    324061  324287  226 +   ENSG00000237094:I7
chr1    324288  324345  57  +   ENSG00000237094:E8
chr1    324346  324438  92  +   ENSG00000237094:I8
chr1    324439  326514  2075    +   ENSG00000237094:E9
**chr1  326096  326569  473 +   ENSG00000250575:E1**
chr1    326515  327551  1036    +   ENSG00000237094:I9
**chr1  326570  327347  777 +   ENSG00000250575:I1**
**chr1  327348  328112  764 +   ENSG00000250575:E2**
chr1    327552  328453  901 +   ENSG00000237094:E10
chr1    328454  329783  1329    +   ENSG00000237094:I10
**chr1  329431  329620  189 -   ENSG00000233653:E2**
**chr1  329621  329949  328 -   ENSG00000233653:I1**
chr1    329784  329976  192 +   ENSG00000237094:E11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer:

```
sed 's/:[EI]/&_ /' foo.txt |  #separate the number at the end with a space
sort -k6 | sort -n -k7 |         #sort by code, then by [EI] number
sed 's/_ //'                  #remove the underscore space
```

I like to do things like this by 'protecting' strings with a placeholder to isolate what I'm interested in, then replacing them later.

Closer:

```
sed 's/:[EI]/_ &_ /' foo.txt | sort -n -k8 | sort -k6,6 | sed 's/_ //g'
```

But this naively assumes that sort works in a very specific way that it doesn't... so sometimes E2 will come before E1...

I'm not sure it can be done with sort alone, awk might be the way to go...

Comment: Thanks for the solution @scf , however when I was doing absolute sorting for k7 it gave me E and I 11 before E2 and I2 so I made a small change in the command as sed 's/:[EI]/&_ /' file | sort -k6 | sort -V -k7 | sed 's/_ //'. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually it is still not working for some rows  : chr10 101380367 101418901 38534 - ENSG00000155287:I1
chr10 101380812 101381675 863 + ENSG00000260475:E1
chr10 101411968 101413581 1613 - ENSG00000229278:I1
chr10 101413582 101413662 80 - ENSG00000229278:E1
chr10 101418902 101418994 92 - ENSG00000155287:E1

Comment: On my version of sort it's `sort -n` updating the answer now

Comment: I didn't quiet get your last comment

Comment: I wasn't at a computer, so I didn't have the man page to check what -V did, I should have used `sort -n` in my answer : -n, --numeric-sort compare according to string numerical value

Answer (score 1):

So I came back to this question and wrote some python code that actually accomplishes the task:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re
from collections import defaultdict

#loop through args
for thisarg in sys.argv[1:]:
    #initialize a defualt dict
    bysign = defaultdict(list)

    #read the file
    try:
        thisfile = open(thisarg,'r')
        for line in thisfile:
            #split each line by space and colon
            dat = re.split('[ :]*',line.strip())
            #append line to dictionary indexed by ENSG code
            bysign[dat[-2]].append(line.strip())
        thisfile.close()
    except IOError:
        print "no such file {:}".format(thisarg)

    #extract the keys from the dictionary
    mykeys = bysign.keys()
    #sort the keys
    mykeys.sort()
    for key in mykeys:
        #initialize another, smaller dictionary
        bytuple = dict()
        #loop through all the lines that have the same ENSG code
        group = bysign[key]
        for line in group:
            #extract the E/I code
            ei=line.split(':')[-1]
            #convert the E/I code to a (char,int) tuple
            letter = ei[0]
            number = int(ei[1:])
            #use that tuple to index the smaller dict
            bytuple[(letter,number)] = line
        #extract the keys from the sub-dictionary
        eikeys = bytuple.keys()
        #sort the keys
        eikeys.sort()
        #print the results
        for k in eikeys:
            print bytuple[k]
```

I hope you already figured it out by now. Curious if anyone cares enough to improve my python.